# Writing two variables in a file via chef file resource content

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Is it possible to write two variables to a file generated by chef - without using a template erb file?

```
username = secret[:username]
password = secret[:password]

file "/home/secret_file.txt" do
  content username password
  owner 'user'
  group 'user'
  mode '0755'
end
```

Adding only one variable is working as expected but with two variables as shown above I get a error message "undefined method `username' for Chef::Resource::File"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to add these variables in one line in the file? The content property takes a string type.

You could do use string interpolation to create a string and add the content to the file:

```
username = secret[:username]
password = secret[:password]

file "/home/secret_file.txt" do
  content "#{username} #{password}"
  owner 'user'
  group 'user'
  mode '0755'
end
```

or if you need to format it a certain way:

```
username = secret[:username]
password = secret[:password]
output = <<-CODE
The username is #{username}
The password is #{password}
CODE

file "/home/secret_file.txt" do
  content output
  owner 'user'
  group 'user'
  mode '0755'
end
```

Comment: Although once a user hits the need to format something they should really be using a template resource...

Comment: Yes, definitely agree with you @lamont.